# Checking if user exists in database not working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
$checkemail = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM loginInfo WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
$checkemail->bind_param('s', $un);
$checkemail->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
$checkemail->store_result();

if ($checkemail->num_rows == 1) {
    echo 'error';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Error. User already exists.");</script>';
}else {
    // insert into table
}
```

Not sure why this is not working it allows me to create a user over and over again

**Edit**: After trying again it doesn't insert any records with the same email into the database but the pop up alert is not appearing

Comment: Have you checked the actual results of the query? Are you 100% sure that your query is OK?
Also, `> 0` is generally safer than `== 1`. I remember having a similar issue with `== 1`. I believe because it returned a row saying something like `no results found`  when no results were found, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @babydead I just tried 10 times and I was wrong, it doesnt insert into the database.. The popup javascript alert is not working though

Comment: I think you should use `$checkemail->num_rows >= 1`

Comment: I just tested your code (like a literal copy-paste, only making sure it always hits the error) and it works fine for me.
Are you 100% sure that you didn't check "Don't show any more dialog boxes from this website"?  - Also, does it echo the "error" part? If it doesn't, you're not getting into the if statement.